# BigCommerce API Category Update Doesn't Work

Tags: bigcommerce

I submitted a BigCommerce category update with this code:

```
curl -X PUT  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Client: <auth client>" -H "X-Auth-Token: <auth token>" -H "X-Custom-Auth-Header: <custom auth header>" -d '{\"data\":{\"id\":2876,\"parent_id\":30,\"name\":\"Health, Fitness & Recreation\",\"description\":\"\",\"views\":0,\"sort_order\":2620,\"page_title\":\"\",\"meta_keywords\":[\"\"],\"meta_description\":\"\",\"layout_file\":\"category.html\",\"image_url\":\"https://catalog.progressivepii.com/Images/eItems/237834_Full.jpg\",\"is_visible\":true,\"search_keywords\":\"\",\"default_product_sort\":\"use_store_settings\",\"custom_url\":{\"url\":\"/furniture-furnishings/health-fitness-recreation/\",\"is_customized\":false}},\"meta\":{}}' "https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/t4yqg98af9/v3/catalog/categories/2876"
```

I got no errors on the call.  It returned the JSON response.  However, the response was the *old* values and did not reflect my changes.  What's going on?  It should either return an error or update my changes.

Randy Kaempen
Intellex Corporation

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample cURL request that is working for updating a category on Bigcommerce.

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{STORE_HASH}/v2/categories/18' \
--header 'X-Auth-Token: {ACCESS_TOKEN}' \
--header 'X-Auth-Client: {CLIENT_ID}' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"name": "A Different Category Name"}'
```

It looks like you are attempting to update with data that is inside a `data` object, you are also sending a `meta` object, and sending the `id` in the body of the request, all of which is not correct.
Try using this as the request body

```
{
    "parent_id": 30,
    "name": "Health, Fitness & Recreation",
    "description": "",
    "sort_order": 2620,
    "page_title": "",
    "meta_keywords": "KEYWORDS",
    "meta_description": "",
    "layout_file": "category.html",
    "is_visible": true
  }
```

Try sending a `PUT` request to this url: `https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{STORE_HASH}/v2/categories/2876`